# How to filter out information in Wireshark

Tags: networking, internet, ip-address, wireshark

I am not interested in any information about network activity from any address that starts with 192.168. How can I make Wireshark hide those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enter this into the `Filter:` field:

```
!(ip.src >= 192.168.0.0 and ip.src <=192.168.255.255)
```

and click on `Apply`. If you want to hide activity going *to* those addresses as well,
change `ip.src` to `ip.addr`.

Comment: `!(ip.src == 192.168.0.0/16)` will probably work as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you know before you take the recording you will not want those messages, you can use a Capture Filter to avoid getting them in the first place.  Specify it in the "Capture Options" dialog.  These use a different syntax to the Display Filters like in the previous answer.

not src net 192.168.0.0 mask 255.255.0.0

Comment: `not src net 192.168.0.0/16` will probably work as well.